# Search to all label that contains specific string then change it to a declared value

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am new just wanted to ask for advice I wanted to search to all the labels and change all the value that contains specific string then change it to a declared value. Below code is running but problem is if there is a label like John,Johny or eric and erica

and I used this code

```
$("label:contains('John')").text("Hi");
$("label:contains('eric')").text("Hello");
```

It will change John to hi but even Johny will be change to hi since both of them contains John same as eric and erica both will be changed to hello I will really apppreciate any advice

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in plain JavaScript:

```
var label = document.querySelector("label");
var name = "John";
var regex = new RegExp(`^${name}$`);
if (name === label.innerHTML) label.innerHTML = name.replace(regex, 'Hi');
```